# Heroku does not install toolbelt PATH by default on OSX with bash

Tags: heroku

Installing heroku-toolbelt/2.32.9 on OSX 10.7.4 fails to setup the PATH correctly for bash.

To fix this I created a `.bash_profile` with a correct PATH:

```
$ cat ~/.bash_profile 
export PATH=/usr/local/heroku/bin/:$PATH
```

Answer (score 2):

I did this instead:

```
$ touch ~/.bash_profile 
export PATH=/usr/local/heroku/bin/:$PATH
```